# Sum to zero of all triples in a list - n^2 running time

Tags: python, algorithm, interview-questions, complexity

As part of an interview, I had to submit a code sample to solve the classical "triples sum to 0" problem. The reviewer said the algorithm needed to be in *n*<sup>2</sup> time, and I was later informed that the code I wrote did not accomplish this.

Can you guys help me identify where I went wrong? I've written comments explaining my thought process.

```
# Small struct to hold the values we need for computing unique sums
DoubleSum = namedtuple('DoubleSum', 'arg_sum int1 int2 int1_index int2_index')


def sum_zero(integers: [int]) -> [(int, int, int)]:
    """
    Given a list of integers, compute all triples that sum to 0
    :param integers: The integers to arrange
    :return: All triples that sum to 0, or [] if there are no sums
    """
    # Check for trivial issues
    if integers is None or len(integers) < 3:
        raise ValueError("Must have an input of at least 3 integers to check.")

    s_integers = sorted(integers)

    # Compute all unique possible sums of two integers
    # Should run in n^2
    sums = []
    for i in range(0, len(s_integers)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(s_integers)):
            int1 = s_integers[i]
            int2 = s_integers[j]
            sums.append(DoubleSum(int1+int2, int1, int2, i, j))

    # For each integer, find all two-element sums that would equal 0
    # Should be n^2 - for each integer, find all double sums that match it
    triples = []
    for i in range(0, len(s_integers)):
        current = s_integers[i]
        matches = filter(lambda s: s.arg_sum == -current, sums)
        for match in matches:
            test_triple = (i, match.int1_index, match.int2_index)
            # If the current index isn't below both indices in the sum,
            # we have come across another permutation of a previous sum to 0
            if i < match.int1_index and i < match.int2_index:
                triples.append(test_triple)

            # We could reduce the runtime if we added a break statement to the
            # else clause, but that seems to introduce errors after maintenance
            # when nobody quite remembers what the break did in the first place

    # Map the indices in `triples` to the actual values
    return [(s_integers[t[0]],
             s_integers[t[1]],
             s_integers[t[2]]) for t in triples]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first pair of loops builds the list `sums`. The length of this list is \$O(n^2)\$ in the length of the input.

In your second set of loops *for each element in `s_integers`* you `filter` *all of `sums`* to find those elements which match it. The runtime of this filter process is linear in the length of `sums`, and hence quadratic in the length of the input. You perform this quadratic process once for each member of the input list; the search loop is therefore cubic in the length of the input.

Your algorithm as a whole is therefore \$O(n^3)\$ in the length of the input.

To make the algorithm as a whole quadratic, you need to make the second (match) stage linear *in the length of `sums`*. Natural approaches would include:

- Using a dictionary or some other map structure to lookup elements in the original either `s_integers` or `sums` by magnitude, in constant time; the match stage is then linear in the length of the other list. (Probably fastest on real input; it might be slightly tricky to check that there are no pathological cases, depending on which list you do lookup on).
- Sorting `sums` (\$O(n \log n)\$), then effectively 'merging' `sums` and `s_integers`, (\$O(n)\$ in the length of the larger). This is easiest to prove to be \$O(n^2)\$